# SPFx Field Customizer deployment: main js not loaded from CDN in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, deployment, solution-deployment, spfx-extensions

I try to deploy my first Field Customizer app to a SharePoint online tenant. Tried several things, without CDN and with bundled assets, now using a CDN (which I previously configured with the SharePoint Online Management Shell).
Nothing worked. There are warnings and 404s on the JS console, it seems that the field-customizer js file is not loaded.

[image]

What I did:

1. I added the CDN base path to `config/write-manifests.json`
2. I set `"includeClientAssets": false` in `config/package-solution.json`
3. `gulp clean`
4. `gulp --ship`
5. I copied the files from `<myprojectpath>/temp/deploy` to my CDN location
6. `gulp bundle --ship`
7. `gulp package-solution --ship`
8. Upload and activate .sppkg file
9. made sure that the latest version is running on the target site

Did I miss anything? Are there any other relevant config settings I need to change? Is a CDN necessary at all, can't sharepoint 'automatically' host the js files somewhere when I include them in the package (like in a sharepoint 2013 hosted app)?

UPDATE:

I decided not to host the assts (which is basically one script) in the CDN but bundle it and deploy them directly, I learned that it should be possible.

**But still I don't know how to actually attach the field customizer to a specific field of a specific list. Maybe that's the issue.
In local hosting debug mode you do it with lengthy URL parameters, but how to do it in production?**

Comment: I can only see a 404 for the graph call. Have you activated the feature? Have a look in the docs for how you deploy extension. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer

Comment: @AndersAune I followed that tutorial to build the extension. I worked after some certificate issues when hosted locally. I also followed the deployment steps and that is what I ended up with.

Comment: @AndersAune nope, no idea what the graph call is for

Comment: Did you add the app? Have you checked the network tab to see if your js file has been loaded? The 404 above and the other warnings don't seem to be relevant.

Comment: @MartijnEikelenboom, yes the app is added (latest version). My js file is not loaded at all.

Comment: Well did you deploy the field customizer on a list ? It should start working on that list. Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) link for more guidance on how to deploy it and attach it to a list

Comment: @GautamSheth Thanks, I know that link, thats the tutorial I used to build the field customizer. However, it focuses on debug mode, I could not find how to attach the field customizer to a field without the URL parameters used for debugging

Comment: I found my error of thinking: the field customizer adds a new site column which I must add to my list. I thought it attaches to an existing list column. So the production behaviour is different from the debug-part of the tutorial and quite misleading.

Comment: Yes, the tutorial focuses on the development/debugging of the FieldCustomizer. For production deployment, you will need to deploy the .sppkg file to the app catalog and also have a site column configured with the `ClientSideComponentId` as shown in the Field XML in the tutorial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer#review-the-elementsxml-file This can be set using XML or through CSOM/REST APIs